# Using Terminal Control Codes with C

Tags: c, shell, terminal, command-line-interface, tput

I am interested in creating a terminal-based text interface in C without the use of a library like `ncurses`. I know that through using `tput` and a variety of escape codes, it is possible to create such an interface. However, I am uncertain of how to use `tput` or similar commands in C.

First, I am wondering what the best option is for implementing something like this in C without external libraries (so it can be compiled and run on a bare bone system).

Second, if using `tput` is the best option, how can I call these commands from C?

I understand that using a pre-existing library, such as `ncurses` would greatly simplify the process, but I would like to create my program without them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to create a text mode interface, you almost certainly *DO* want to use a library like ncurses.  Honest!  The "overhead" is modest; the productivity gains and improvements in program robustness are enormous.

Comment: Beyond the obvious: calling `tput` using `system` or `popen`, `tput` uses ncurses anyway.  `tput` is useful for *shell scripts*.

Answer (score 1):

The standard C library does not provide any functions that can be used instead of the functions in `ncurses`. You'll have to use `ncurses` or another third party library that provides the equivalent functionality.

Comment: Is there not a way I could call tput or similar commands directly from C?

Comment: When you say "directly from C", I assume you mean "is there any such function in the standard C library". The answer is "No".